# String reversing method

Tags: ruby

The code does reverse, but it still comes out as negative.

```
def reverse(string1)
  string1 = string1.chomp
  i = 0
  len=string1.length-1
  while (i < len)
    sub = string1[i]
    string1[i] = string1[len]
    string1[len] = sub
    i = i+1
    len= len-1
  end
end

puts('reverse("abc") == "cba": ' + (reverse("abc") == "cba").to_s)
puts('reverse("a") == "a": ' + (reverse("a") == "a").to_s)
puts('reverse("") == "": ' + (reverse("") == "").to_s)
```

How come my code is not coming out as positive? Could it be because of the `\n` string (couldn't possibly be, because I used `chomp` function)?

Comment: Are you doing this as an exercise?  If not, why not just use the `.reverse` method on strings rather than create a method external to string?  Even if you are doing it as an exercise, wouldn't it be much better to monkey patch your method onto the `String` class rather than create an external method for it?  `reverse` is something that a string object should know how to do, not something that I have to know about and call with a string argument. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return `string1` at the end of your function!

Side note: in ruby the value of a function evaluates to the value of the last line of code it executes. You simply need to put a reference to `string1` before the `end` of your reverse function.